# How retrieve the file name from a write strem object

Tags: python, file-io

I've a simple question about file string manipulation.

I've written a bit of code that finally works other than for the final message. For the sake of my explanation, please have a look at a simplified version of my code below.

```
outStream = "/Users/andreamoro/Desktop/domains_output.csv"

try:
    outStream = open(outStream, "w")
    ...
    do something
except:
    ....
else:
    print "A new output file %s has been created." %os.path.basename(outStream)
```

my desired output should be just the filename ... instead I get an exception like this

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 121, in basename
    i = p.rfind('/') + 1
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'rfind'

I'm certainly using the wrong method, and I cannot expect to cast a file type into a string. I'm surprised there is not a method to return just the file name, and if it exist I wasn't able to find it.

Can you please point in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`outStream` variable is reassigned and becomes a file-like object:

```
outStream = open(outStream, "w")
```

Now you can get the name of the file from `outStream.name`:

> name
>
> If the file object was created using open(), the name of the
>   file. Otherwise, some string that indicates the source of the file
>   object, of the form "<...>". This is a read-only attribute and may not
>   be present on all file-like objects.
>   ([docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/bltin-file-objects.html))

```
os.path.basename(outStream.name)  # is equal to 'domains_output.csv'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you re-assigned `outStream` to a file object.

```
outStream = "/Users/andreamoro/Desktop/domains_output.csv"

try:
    outStream = open(outStream, "w")  # now outStream is this
```

Rename either the string object or the file object and your code will work fine.

Otherwise it works fine:

```
>>> strs = "/Users/andreamoro/Desktop/domains_output.csv"
>>> os.path.basename(strs)
'domains_output.csv'
```